# Has anyone succeeded in uploading an image (not a url) via Facebook's SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am looking all over the place for an end to end *working example of using the Android Facebook SDK to upload an image to a user's wall.  I've succeeded in doing this with a link to a web accessible image, but they say it's possible to just submit a byte array, however, when I try this, I just get an empty post on the wall (it even omits the title and description).

I've tried using photo and image as the hash keys for the byte array... my byte array is a perfectly valid Bitmap... So... I'm stumped.  Is this just another buggy Facebook API that doesn't work?  I'd love to know if anyone has used it successfully and maybe take a look at the code you used to see how mine is different.

Here's mine...

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
comboBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);   
Log.d(Constants.TAG, "filled stream");


byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();   

Bundle b = new Bundle();
//b.putString("picture","http://myinkpic.com/images/inkIcon.png");


b.putString("caption", "Stash Title");
b.putString("description", "Stash Caption");
b.putByteArray("photo", bitmapdata);
myApp.facebook.request("me/feed", b, "POST");
```

And here's a link to the dev page where they mention the byte[] 
[Facebook api][1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build)

Notice how they say this:
"Make sure the Bundle value for the photo parameter is a byte array."

That's what gave me the idea to use "photo" as the key.  It may in fact totally wrong, but I can't seem to find the docs now for where they define the keys.

Comment: I used like this. And got null pointer exception at combobitmap.compress..... imagePosition is the URL containing the image.    Bitmap comboBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePostion);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();      comboBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);

Comment: I assume that's because imagePosition needs to be a file on your device and not a URL.

Comment: no.. its a string containing the path http://.... of the image.

Comment: right... so, why would you expect that to work? Where in the documentation do you see decodeFile being able to take a URL of an image that is on the internet?

Comment: however, you're in luck... if the image is already accessible on the internet, then you just use the FB post API and point to it... no need to do any bitmap manipulation whatsoever! My problem was that I needed to upload the file that was NOT on the internet. This continues not to be a feature that Facebook supports.

Comment: thanks. I will try FB post API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after much painful searching and testing it would appear that so long as the request method is "me/feed", posting a byte[] is simply not possible.  What *does work is posting to me/photos.  This has a very similar effect, in that the image does get to the user's gallery and ends up on their wall, but if you post multiple images they all go side by side, rather than in a list.

Hopefull Facebook will release an update sometime in the near term fixing this bug.

Comment: Try passing null instead of "me/feed"

Comment: Note to anyone in the future.. you now CAN post an image directly through the Facebook SDK

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph#add-images-to-actions-and-objects